# File creation date for files in iOS app bundle

Tags: ios

My app includes a database in the bundle.  When this database needs to be updated, the app will download a new version from Firebase storage.  To determine if the database needs updating, it compares the file creation date of the file in the bundle (or in .../Documents if the database had been already updated earlier), with the file creation date in the Firebase storage bucket.

What file creation date is used for files in the app bundle? Is it the date the app was uploaded to the App Store, or the date the user downloads the app?

Comment: You would be better off using a version number, not a timestamp.

Comment: I know, and I may go that route, but it is easier to more robust to compare file dates.  So I would still like to know the answer.

Comment: I don't know about robust and easier doesn't mean correct. But all of that aside, it is an interesting question. But why not run some test code and find out the answer yourself? Test with a simulator build. Test with a proper Test Flight build that contains some test code that shows you the timestamp of the file.

Comment: It seems that the file creation date is when a full build is done.  After a Clean Build Folder, and rebuild, or an Archive, the files from the project are copied into the bundle as expected. That will be the date of the files in the bundle, not the date they were originally copied into your project.